# How to get a Floating Action Button over a scrollable webview in xamarin forms without using additional Nuhget packages?

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Fab.Forms package is not working jn my system. It requires target framework to be changed to .Net Framework from .Net standard. So is there any alternative way of getting a FAB over a webview that can be scrolled. The webview holds a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using grid is a simple way to put FAB on a view that can be scrolled.

This is a sample xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <WebView Grid.Row="0" Source="http://xamarin.com" />

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Text="☆" FontSize="Large" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="OrangeRed" BorderRadius="35" TextColor="White"  WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="70" Margin="0,0,20,22" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End"/>

</Grid>
```